# How do I get all checkboxes.text that is selected by a user on C#

Tags: c#, checkbox

Hello again I need help so I came here.
I just can't figured out how to do this.

But here's what I want
I have a c# form with 6 checkboxes on it. Checkboxes.text value are all Name of programming languages.

[]PHP

[]C

[]C++

[]VB.Net

[]Java

[]C#

Suppose a user click two or more checkboxes how can I display it.

I'm getting confuse on multiple selections part.

Here's my code

For the single selection

```
   If (Checkbox1.Checked == True)
{
MessageBox.Show(CheckBox1.Text);
}
```

For two selection

```
    If (CheckBox1.Checked == True && CheckBox2.Checked == True)
{
MessageBox.Show(CheckBox1.Text);
}
```

I use If statements on checkboxes for single or even more selected checkboxes.

How can I code it easier or even simplier. Is it possible?

Comment: Create a list of strings and do an if for each checkbox, if checked add the name to the list. Then after just do a `string.Join(" ", list);`.

Answer (score 1):

### Here i am saying the answer for the question by using tech like C# and Windows Presentation Form.

1.First you need to create a global function for all the check boxes.
Ex:-Function Name-Check_Checked

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 10 0 0">
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Weld" x:Name="WeldCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Assembly" x:Name="AssemblyCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Plasma"  x:Name="PlasmaCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Laser"  x:Name="LaserCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Purchase"  x:Name="PurchaseCheck"/>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 10 0 0">
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Lathe" x:Name="LatheCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Drill" x:Name="DrillCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Fold" x:Name="FoldCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Roll" x:Name="RollCheck"/>
<CheckBox Checked="Check_Checked" Content="Saw" x:Name="SawCheck"/>
</StackPanel>
```

2.define the function in C#

```
private void Check_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.LengthText.Text += (string)((CheckBox)sender).Content;
        MessageBox.Show(this.LengthText.Text);
    }
```

With only one line of code you get the names of the check boxes in the text box and also in message box.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all form's controls and get text properties of checked CheckBoxes with LINQ in one line:

```
    private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> checkedItems=(from Control c in Controls where c is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)c).Checked select c.Text).ToList();
        MessageBox.Show(string.Join(";", checkedItems));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do like that:
make checkboxes list and then itterate through them:

```
List<string>Result=new List<string>();

Checkbox[] checkBox=new CheckBox[6];
checkBox[0]=checkBox1;
checkBox[1]=checkBox2;
checkBox[2]=checkBox3;
checkBox[3]=checkBox4;
checkBox[4]=checkBox5;
checkBox[5]=checkBox6;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if(checkBox[i].Checked)
    {
        Result.Add(checkBox[i].Text);
    }
}
```

And then do whatever you want with this Result list

Answer (score 0):

Young grasshopper, you will most commonly do this type of operation in two steps:

1. Collect the statuses.
2. Display the summary of the statuses.

C# WinForms Example:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();       // this will be your message

    // 1. Loop over all the controls in the form and collect the statuses.
    // (if you want to limit it to only some checkboxes you could put them 
    // in a gui container or array, and loop over yourContainer.Controls instead.)
    foreach (var cb in Controls)        
    {
        // append to string if this is a checkbox AND it is checked
        var c = cb as CheckBox;
        if (c != null && c.Checked)    
        {
            sb.Append(c.Text + "\n");  // ps "\n" is a new line in the message
        }
    }

    // 2. display the message if any checkbox was selected.
    var message = sb.ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) // not empty?
        MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```